# Cannot understand Chrome Heap Snapshot of GWT ArrayList

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, arraylist, heap-dump

I have a simple gwt project and i am using ArrayList in that.

I took a heap snapshot to check memory usage. Here it is showing some memory even though that arraylist is Empty.

[image]

Am i doing anything wrong? or Misunderstanding usage of arraylists in GWT?

Please help me to understand the heap snapshot.

Thanks,
PK

Comment: That is the memory used by the implementation of a java object in javascript, this memory would vary when your code is full obfuscated/optimized. I would not worry about that you should focus in your own business objects

Comment: Thanks @ManoloCarrascoMoñino . Memory reduced after changing compile style to OBFUSCATED